# How do I upgrade sql server 2012 RTM to sql server 2012 SP1

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm really confused by the 2 different editions of SQL Server 2012. There is RTM and SP1 which both seem like different code branches. How do I upgrade an RTM install to a SP1 install. I've tried upgrade and that doesn't let me choose the old RTM install.

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade SQL from RTM to SP1 using SP1 installation media? Wouldn't it be easier to just install SP1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm really confused by the 2 different editions of SQL Server 2012.

But you ARE an admin, right?

> There is RTM and SP1 which both seem like different code branches.

No. it is the same like any SERVICE PACK. RTM is the released original, SP1 the first service pack. EXACTLY the same like XP, Windows 7 - not windows 8 where the SP is called 8.1. Same like exchange. Like any enterprise software.

> How do I upgrade an RTM install to a SP1 install.

Download the SP1 installer, run it.

> I've tried upgrade and that doesn't let me choose the old RTM install.

Why not? Check version numbers. We need a lot more info. For example error info, or what it sees - there is a nice dialog telling you which windows versions you have installed.

Comment: Hi no I'm not an admin, this isn't really my job. Installing SP1 as straight install fixed it. Thanks. Upgrade wouldn't pick up 11.0.2218 as a candidate for upgrade. Now on version 11.0.3000

Comment: Next time ;) You can use http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/ to check version numbers ;) What you had there was not a RTM but a slightly patched one.... should still show up as available.